# How to get attachment id of background image?

Tags: responsive, custom-background

I'm looking for a way to get the ID of the background_image when I am using custom headers?

I tired using `url_to_postid` like this:

```
$url = get_header_image()
$postid = url_to_postid( $url );
```

and
    $url = get_theme_mod('header-image')
    $postid = url_to_postid( $url );

I got a null value for both, which I realized is because both `get_header_image()` and `get_theme_mod('header-image')` return the url in the form of example.com/wp-content/uploads... but what `url_to_postid` needs is example.com/?attachment_id=#.

I also thought about `get_theme_mods();` but it only returns the long url for background image. Not the shorter url or the ID. It does give the id for the header image though, grrr.

What am I missing here?

For the record I'm doing this so I can get the background image with `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` in a dynamic stylesheet and use the $size arg, with some custom sizes to return a different size depending on the screen size. That way I can do full screen backgrounds without having to load and scale down some massive image for a phone's screen. Alternative solutions to my actual problem are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Query for post meta keys `_wp_attachment_is_custom_background` or `_wp_attachment_is_custom_background`:

```
function t5_bg_img_id()
{
    if ( ! $bg_img = get_background_image() )
        return FALSE;

    $query = array(
        'post_type'  => 'attachment',
        'fields'     => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array (
            array (
                'key' => '_wp_attachment_is_custom_background',
                'value'   => get_option( 'stylesheet' ),
                'compare' => '==',
            ),
            array (
                'key' => '_wp_attachment_metadata',
                'value'   => basename( $bg_img ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    );

    if ( array () === $bg_post = get_posts( $query ) )
        return FALSE;

    return $bg_post[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it returned false, though I'm not sure if I follow how to implement it.  I tried to echo $bg_post, just to see if I got a value, and I did not.